# Why is there no screen warping software for Linux and how to approach a solution?

Tags: opengl, image-processing

I've got a curved canvas on which I want to project a 3D game using multiple projectors. Obviously, the image will be distorted and needs some correction, e.g. using [softwarp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softwarp).

For Windows, there are a lot of tools, like [this](https://fly.elise-ng.net/index.php/products/immersive-display-pro), [this](http://www.scalabledisplay.com/products/scalable-display-manager/), [this](http://www.vioso.com/downloads.php) and [this](http://www.immersaview.com/blend-warp/). But there seems to be nothing similar for Linux.

Are there any inherent technical limitations that prevent such software to exist at all?

If not, what would be a good point to start implementing a system-wide or application-specific screen warping software?
Maybe something of the following:

- a [detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/)-like interception of rendering calls
- adding a stage to the OpenGL rendering pipeline
- compositors effects, like the Compiz Wobbly Windows plugin

I am not familiar with any of those techniques, so I cannot tell, if any of those is suited at all.

Comment: A quick web search gives [this](http://projection-mapping.org/splash/) and [this](https://mapmapteam.github.io/)

Comment: As far as I can see, those are only video players with built-in warping and edge blending. They are not able to distort 3rd party applications or whole screens.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't exist because nobody did implement it. Technically implementing this in Linux is even easier than on any other mainstream OS. The keyword is "compositing". You can implement this through one of the compositing methods.

For X11/Xorg based desktops through the `Composite` X extension, either as a standalone compositor, or as a plugin for Compiz, Emerald or anothee extensible compositing WM.

With Wayland it'd boil down to implementing a warping system compositor onto which a regular session compositor is launched.